How to still use sidebar after navigating inside a view padOS?
I have an app that i will run on iPad. I am setting up the sidebar but am stuck. I want to be able to select a page and then navigate within that selected page to other pages.
What is happening at the moment is, I am selecting between pages just fine in the sidebar and then in the main view, if I press a button that moves me away from that main view to another one, the sidebar becomes useless. I have to press "Back" to get back to the initial view that was chosen from the sidebar and then the sidebar becomes active again.
In the example app - if you go to "wx on Arrival" from the sidebar and then press the "Go settings" button in there to the "second layer" the sidebar doesn't work...
What I want to happen is: Regardless of how deep I go into a single selected sidebar view, I want to be able to select any of the sidebar options and go straight to what I am trying to go to. Thank you.
Here Is a very simple reproducible version of the problem, I apologise for the many pages:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct scrapAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MenuView()
        }
    }
}

funcs.swift
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var destination: String = ""
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    @Published var selectedItem: SidebarItem?
    @Published var readyToNavigate : Bool = false
    
}

MenuView.swift
enum SidebarItem: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case initialScreen = "Initial Screen"
    case arrivalWx = "Wx On Arrival"
    case legal = "Legal"

    var id: String { self.rawValue }

    var iconName: String {
        switch self {
        case .initialScreen:
            return "house"
        case .arrivalWx:
            return "cloud.sun"
        case .legal:
            return "doc.text"
        }
    }
}

struct MenuView: View {
    @StateObject private var app = AppState()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(SidebarItem.allCases, id: \.self, selection: $app.selectedItem) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    Label(item.rawValue, systemImage: item.iconName)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Menu")
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $app.path) {
                if let selectedItem = app.selectedItem {
                    switch selectedItem {
                    case .initialScreen:
                        FirstPage()
                    case .arrivalWx:
                        SecondPage(app: app)
                    case .legal:
                        FourthPage(app: app)
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("Select an item")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

FirstPage.swift
struct FirstPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("INITIAL SCREEN")
    }
}

SecondPage.swift
struct SecondPage: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("WX on ARRIVAL")
        Button("Go settings") {
            app.readyToNavigate = true
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.readyToNavigate) {
            ThirdPage()
        }
    }
}

ThirdPage.swift
struct ThirdPage: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var app = AppState()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second Layer")
    }
}

FourthPage.swift
struct FourthPage: View {
    @ObservedObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("LEGAL") {
        }
    }
}


AFAIK, in iPadOS in portrait mode this is the default behaviour. In landscape mode
you can have the sidebar and the navigation at the same time.
Note, since you are using the AppState in many child views,
I recommend you use .environmentObject(app) in the top view and
in the child views @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState instead
of passing the model everywhere, with potential mistakes like you have in
ThirdPage redeclaring the model.

Thank you @workingdog support Ukraine I have changed to EnvironmentObject now. I have tried in landscape and it seems to behave in the same way, where - once "go settings" button has been pressed, the sidebar items have no effect. What I have also noticed is that, if in the "settings" page and "Legal" is pressed in sidebar, when "Back" is pressed, the page displayed is "Legal"... Confusing

I'm not getting any of your problems.
You sayI want to be able to select a page and then navigate within that selected page to other pages. This is the behaviour I get on iPadOS 17.5.1.
Also ...the sidebar becomes useless, I do not get this at all,
the sidebar remains responsive at all time. I'll post my test code.

Here is my test code that works for me on iPadOS 17.5.1.
struct MenuView: View {
    @StateObject private var app = AppState()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(SidebarItem.allCases, selection: $app.selectedItem) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    Label(item.rawValue, systemImage: item.iconName)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Menu")
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $app.path) {
                if let selectedItem = app.selectedItem {
                    switch selectedItem {
                    case .initialScreen:
                        FirstPage()
                    case .arrivalWx:
                        SecondPage()
                    case .legal:
                        FourthPage()
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("Select an item")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(app)  // <--- here
        }
    }
}

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var destination: String = ""
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    @Published var selectedItem: SidebarItem?
    @Published var readyToNavigate: Bool = false
}

enum SidebarItem: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case initialScreen = "Initial Screen"
    case arrivalWx = "Wx On Arrival"
    case legal = "Legal"

    var id: String { self.rawValue }

    var iconName: String {
        switch self {
        case .initialScreen:
            return "house"
        case .arrivalWx:
            return "cloud.sun"
        case .legal:
            return "doc.text"
        }
    }
}

struct FirstPage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState // not used
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("FirstPage INITIAL SCREEN")
    }
}

struct SecondPage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("SecondPage WX on ARRIVAL")
        Button("Go settings") {
            app.readyToNavigate = true
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.readyToNavigate) {
            ThirdPage()
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdPage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState  // not used
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("ThirdPage Second Layer")
    }
}

struct FourthPage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState  // not used
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("FourthPage LEGAL") {
        }
    }
}

Note, I meant to say that in portrait mode, the sidebar disappears, but in landscape mode, it stays visible.

Thanks very much @workingdog support Ukraine I have copied and pasted your code verbatim. I get the same behaviour as before. What I mean when I say it becomes useless is that, when I am on the ThirdPage which has been navigated to via Button, pressing Initial Screen or Legal in the sidebar does not navigate. I have to press the Back button before the navigation via the sidebar becomes visible. If this is what you get and the expected behaviour, thats no worries I will work with it. Thank you!

I wonder if a simultaneousGesture() might work to wipe the NavigationPath() when a side bar item is pressed? Not sure thats the right way to go about it though.

Like I said, I'm do not get any of these problems with my code.
When I am on the ThirdPage which has been navigated to via Button, pressing Initial Screen or Legal in the sidebar does navigate for me.
The sidebar is active. What system are you using and targeting. I am now on MacOS 15, Xcode 16-beta, target iOS-17.5, tested on real (older) iPad device and MacCatalyst.

Ok I was using the simulator and it wasn't working, I have run it now on an actual iPad and it works well. I am using MacOS 14.2 Xcode 15 and target iOS 17 or greater. iPad that it is working on is iOS 17.3. Thank you for the help, much appreciated.

Glad it is working now. If my answer helped you, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.
